# php file upload signalled by js

Tags: javascript, php, file, fwrite

I am getting a POST from js by XMLHttprequest.send.
When I press F12 in Chrome i can see that POST is sent ok.
But when my php handler is called and attempts to write the sent image.png to tmp.png file the result file size is zero. What am I doing wrong?
[Edited]
I changed php handler. New version below. Exception is thrown saying Invalid parameters.

Heres my code:

js:

```
let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
let formData = new FormData();

formData.append("photo", blob);                                 
req.open("POST", 'clipboard_write.php');
req.send(formData);
```

clipboard_write.php:

```
<?php
try {
    // Undefined | Multiple Files | $_FILES Corruption Attack
    // If this request falls under any of them, treat it invalid.
    if (
        !isset($_FILES['upfile']['error']) ||
        is_array($_FILES['upfile']['error'])
    ) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Invalid parameters.');
    }
?>
```

Comment: File uploads are in `$_FILES`, not `$_POST`.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files and have a robust file-upload subsystem.

Comment: @Barmar I changed code as in the link. Now it gives me exception Invalid parameters. Why?

Comment: Did you change `$_FILES['upfile']` to `$_FILES['photo']` to match the parameter you gave to `formData.append()`?

Comment: Thank you, changed to photo and now it works!!!

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you might do something like this with your **JavaScript**:

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* js/external.js */
let get, post, doc, html, bod, nav, M, I, mobile, S, Q, aC, rC, tC; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
get = (url, success, context)=>{
  const x = new XMLHttpRequest;
  const c = context || x;
  x.open('GET', url);
  x.onload = ()=>{
    if(success)success.call(c, JSON.parse(x.responseText));
  }
  x.send();
}
post = function(url, send, success, context){
  const x = new XMLHttpRequest;
  const c = context || x;
  x.open('POST', url);
  x.onload = ()=>{
    if(success)success.call(c, JSON.parse(x.responseText));
  }
  if(typeof send === 'object' && send && !(send instanceof Array)){
    if(send instanceof FormData){
      x.send(send);
    }
    else{
      const fd = new FormData;
      for(let k in send){
        fd.append(k, JSON.stringify(send[k]));
      }
      x.send(fd);
    }
  }
  else{
    throw new Error('send argument must be an Object');
  }
  return x;
}
doc = document; html = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body; nav = navigator; M = tag=>doc.createElement(tag); I = id=>doc.getElementById(id);
mobile = nav.userAgent.match(/Mobi/i) ? true : false;
S = (selector, within)=>{
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = (selector, within)=>{
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
aC = function(){
  const a = [].slice.call(arguments), n = a.shift();
  n.classList.add(...a);
  return aC;
}
rC = function(){
  const a = [].slice.call(arguments), n = a.shift();
  n.classList.remove(...a);
  return rC;
}
tC = function(){
  const a = [].slice.call(arguments), n = a.shift();
  n.classList.toggle(...a);
  return tC;
}
// magic happens under here
const upload = I('upload'), upload_error = I('upload_error');
upload.onfocus = ()=>{
  rC(upload_error, 'ya'); upload_error.textContent = 'file required'; 
}
upload.onchange = function(){
  let files = this.files, file, fd;
  if(files.length){
    if(this.value.match(/\.(png|jpe?g|gif|bmp)$/i)){
      file = files[0];
      if(file.size > 10485760){
        upload_error.textContent = 'file must be 10 MB or less';
      }
      else{
        fd = new FormData; fd.append('uploaded_img', file);
        upload_error.textContent = 'waiting on server';
        post('yourPage.php', fd, o=>{
          // o would be response object
          if(o.success){
            upload_error.textContent = 'upload success'; aC(upload_error, 'good');
          }
          else{
            // o.hacks has hacks
          }
          this.blur();
        });
      }
    }
    else{
      upload_error.textContent = 'must be a common image extension';
    }
  }
}
upload.onerror = function(){
  this.blur(); upload_error.textContent = 'upload error';
}
}); // end load
//]]>
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
html,body{
  background:#ccc;
}
.er{
  color:#900; margin-left:7px;
}
.er.good{
  color:#090;
}
```

```html
<input id='upload' type='file' />
<div class='er' id='upload_error'>file required</div>
```

Your **PHP** might look like:

```
<?php /* yourPage.php */
if(isset($_FILES['uploaded_img'])){
  $o = new StdClass; $img = $_FILES['uploaded_img']; $name = basename($img['name']);
  if(preg_match('/\.(png|jpe?g|gif|bmp)$/i', $name)){
    $o->hacks[] = 'must be a common image extension';
    // must be a weird hack since this was checked on the Client already
  }
  if($img['size'] > 10485760){
    $o->hacks[] = 'file size must be 10 MB or less';
    // must be a weird hack since this was checked on the Client already
  }
  if(!isset($o->hacks)){
    move_uploaded_file($img['temp_name'], 'images/'.$name); $o->success = true;
  }
  echo json_encode($o);
}
?>
```

Comment: What's with all the cryptic names like `S`, `Q`, etc.? It seems like you have lots of code here that isn't really related to the upload process and obscures the answer.

Comment: I threw those in, in case OP wants to use `.querySelector` and `.querySelectorAll`. It's so OP can get whatever Element nearly anyway they want. Also, it shows technique to OP. Should only take a couple of seconds to read.